# More concise code which confirms the loop was ran, at least, once

Tags: python, loops

I have here a section of code I was working for a program I will be providing support (hopefully) years to come.

In here, I need to confirm if all image files (they are definitely image files pillow supports, at this stage) are valid and not corrupted.

As part of this process. In this process, I tried to make a good balance between performance and easy to read.

```
    to_analysis_files = \
        map(lambda img_file: Image.open(img_file),
            itertools.chain(
                a_path.glob(file.stem + '.*'),
                b_path.glob(file.stem + '.*'),
                c_path.glob(file.stem + '.*'),
            )
        )
    files_were_found = False

    try:
        for im in to_analysis_files:
            files_were_found = True
            im.verify()
    except Exception as e:
        LOG.warning("Faulty image. Got exception %s", str(e), exc_info=True)
    else:
        if files_were_found:
            LOG.info("Images exist and pass. %s", file)
            continue
```

Note:
The `continue` is there because this is part of a relatively large `for` loop. I don't really have much say in that matter, I'm basically stuck with it.

The requirements here are:

1. If at least, 1 image is faulty, the main part of the program is run
2. If there are no images there, the main part of the program is run
3. If there's, at least, 1 image there and they are not faulty, then the program doesn't need to run

I have no control over the requirements.
The code above works and does its job.

** **My main concern.** **

There's that `files_were_found` variable that is just a flag and doesn't seem to be doing anything much besides just being set to true over and over again, just for an if that comes later. For me, it appears to be slowing down the speed at a programmer can read this piece of code.

Are there any recommendations or ideas on how to remove `files_were_found` or, at least, have it in a way it doesn't consume lines like the code above?

Comment: The way the code is written `files_were_found == true` is equivalent to `len(to_analysis_files) > 0`. So couldn’t you simply replace `if files_were_found:` with `if to_analysis_files:`? Although it’s hard to say without a bit more info about how the outer loop works …

Comment: @besc `map` returns an iterator. `len` cannot be used with an iterator.  
Thanks for trying, though

Comment: Your requirements are unclear. What are you supposed to do if there is one faulty and one non-faulty image? That’s both case 1 and case 3.

Comment: @gnasher729 One faulty image is enough for the code to continue this iteration. See the `except` block. I fixed the english for the 3rd condition. Is it more clear?

Comment: Fair enough, although i would be looking to see if that had a method that returned pass/fail instead, or kludging a wrapper method to do just that. As for the SO post, I must have read your issue wrong. What you are looking at doing is manually iterating an iterator using the [iterator protocol](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_iterators.asp) (next and get). You would essential call `next(myit)` manually first, if it failed with StopIteration then the list is empty, do the empty behaviour. Otherwise execute the verification, and grab the `next(myit)`. Failure here is expected as the end

Comment: @Kain0_0 Oh! Right! I could use a generator that calls the `next` separately and has an except for `StopIteration`! (I don't like w3s, btw... Even though nothing wrong with that specific page...). I had completely forgotten such simple function in python. Thank you.